# Typescript error: Property 'prevUrl' is missing despite being declared in the props object

Tags: typescript, next.js

props.prevUrl Property 'prevUrl' does not exist on type '{ nextUrl: string; } | { prevUrl: string; nextUrl: string; } | { prevUrl: string; confirm: () => void; }'.
How to fix?

```
function NavigationButtons({
  variant,
  ...props
}:
  | {
      variant: 'first';
      nextUrl: string;
    }
  | { variant: 'middle'; prevUrl: string; nextUrl: string }
  | { variant: 'last'; prevUrl: string; confirm: () => void }) {
  return (
    <nav
      className={`fixed bottom-0 left-0 right-0 flex bg-neutral-white p-4 ${
        variant === 'first' && 'justify-end'
      } lg:static lg:mt-auto`}
    >
      {(variant === 'middle' || variant === 'last') && (
        <Link href={props.prevUrl}>
          <button>Go Back</button>
        </Link>
      )}
      {(variant === 'first' || variant === 'middle') && (
        <button className='rounded bg-primary-marine-blue px-4 py-2 text-neutral-alabaster'>
          Next Step
        </button>
      )}
      {variant === 'last' && <button>Confirm</button>}
    </nav>
  );
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qytAX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since you destruct the props at the beginning, you separate `variant` from the `props`, which makes the independent, thus the compiler can't narrow the `props` based on the `variant`'s value. The simplest way would be to not use destruct as follows:

```
function NavigationButtons(props:
  | {
      variant: 'first';
      nextUrl: string;
    }
  | { variant: 'middle'; prevUrl: string; nextUrl: string }
  | { variant: 'last'; prevUrl: string; confirm: () => void }) {
  return (
    <div>
       {(props.variant === 'middle' || props.variant === 'last') && <a href={props.prevUrl} /> }
    </div>
  )
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoczAVwDsNgJa4A5FAN2AHMUZHaAQtRgwmAZwAUYHGDEAucnDgAfOAG9FSrexRRgKWjDkFMwKGJhlNWuLSQAPGAFUoAG2MW9tLhRsBfTVU1OB09AyMCEGAAE2jXJDI4aSR2F3c4T2BvUlsHZzcPGC8uOAClIJDdfUNjfFcUC0Tk1IKMoqyfODQmUygQYwkASjgAXgA+EIgY0uGNJSIYaihmCWs4AB5aDjWlNHqxMTYQJBG1AANTeyRouAAjCBFcAFoABjh4zBhXuD0uAAsvm9MPF7HcuE87MIoChXE8AO5-YAwJBJJ4AFjgABI5jYtNIILIAHSharwEbkkxmRpwABkNIIACtqBZgJgAJ5PJC0aL4Hald5cOQWXjANACuQgL4oYQQM5lLRjPlqKQyMTEqrhUYU-BRWLxfAqVT4okkzXkkYEfaWYZ0uCrXFadYoOB-IiYU7GtXNNJ+RUOmzrW7CUS0MYAcQgcAE6AA1usAPRBx6hvlKBMoP24wbymzKz3qsKGLUW-C9anKI2qguk4uRGJxBI2+n2-2B4NMLr7Q4oY4jQgQOjRa5gp7SUC6DkgKp2J63VzUFFgezopIcgBMcGRjghSChMKeMJQtwayKg+Ez-tYeTgAGVkWBUxtE+2Uw7s0r86ai+bLSeDba22TMYAGEejMEAEyTEMxhzJ8tnYTNBgoPwgA)